# Creating a Monix Observable from a NuProcess ByteBuffer

Tags: scala, observable, reactive, bytebuffer, monix

So I have a current project that uses Java `Process` and I am trying to replace it with NuProcess (i.e. https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess). For dealing with Java `Process`'s STDOUT/STDERROR you have had an `InputStream` and since Monix provided a handy interopt method `Observable.fromInputStream`, this allowed you to easily create an `Observable[String]`/`Observable[Array[Byte]]`.

However the issue is that `NuProcess` doesn't work with `InputStream`, instead it uses javas NIO `ByteBuffer`. Ontop of this its slightly more complex because it uses an event handling mechanism, i.e. to listen to `STDOUT`/`STDERROR` in Monix task for `NuProcess` you have to do something like

```scala
nuProcess.setProcessHandler(new NuProcessHandler {
  override def onStderr(buffer: ByteBuffer, closed: Boolean) = {
    if (!closed) {
      val bytes = new Array[Byte](buffer.remaining())
      buffer.get(bytes)
      // Do something else here
    }
  }

  override def onStdout(buffer: ByteBuffer, closed: Boolean) = {
    if (!closed) {
      val bytes = new Array[Byte](buffer.remaining())
      buffer.get(bytes)
      // Do something else here
    }
  }
})
```

So the question is how would you hook this up to an observable (i.e. an `Observable[String]` or `Observable[Array[Byte]]` without being  inefficient?

Note that I am using Monix 3.x